# IOS : connect to router when "no internet" detected

Tags: ios, network, router

I been through a few topic online but can't fine a solution.

Sometime my internet is offline, and iOS won't let met connect to the local network anymore so I can access the router settings or other local server.

The router have DHCP reservations but my iOS getting the IP automatically, however same issue if I setup a manual IP.

Anyway work around ?

Comment: It should let you do this. Go to settings and choose your network. Then there may be a pop-up that says "no internet connection detected. Connect anyway?" Then hit yes. Does this not work?

Answer (score 1):

I actually managed to connect by entering the IP and router IP manually